# Is there a way to identify a person's email address within a company outlook if you are given the person's name in a data set?

Tags: python-3.x, outlook

I am working through my first python course as it relates to finance and trying to understand a way to apply to my current job. I found code to create an email in outlook and attach a data set to send out, but I do not have each person's email address within the data itself, so I was wondering if there was a way to use python to search outlook based on a person's name then pull that email address in to use for the email? This would be a company outlook system, so I would imagine that I could add the names into the To: field then use auto-populate but I'm trying to remove as many manual tasks as possible. Any initial thoughts that I could being to explore this topic?

Thanks in advance from a newbie!

To be honest, I am not sure where to start here so looking for any ideas.

Comment: What is the relevant snippet of your existing code that creates the email?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/address-book/map-a-display-name-to-an-e-mail-address